# Preposition usage with locations on a webpage

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

For describing a section of webpage, for example, which should it be?

> ...logo **at** the top right of the page...

or

> ...logo **in** the top right of the page...

or

> ...logo **on** the top right of the page...

Comment: IN the top right of the page.

Comment: @VijayaRagavan why "in"? Can you explain a little? For me it looks more like "on the top right of the page".

Comment: @Berker I think “corner” is elided in this case. Otherwise, one would probably say “at the top of the page” (to avoid confusion with z-axis top-ness) or “on the right/left [side] of the page”.

Comment: I don't think there's anything special about the fact that it's a website. The prepositions and directions are the same as one would use to indicate areas of a piece of paper or painting.

Comment: Thanks guys, so both 'at' and 'on' sound ok, do they? BTW, @TylerJamesYoung, why deleting the 'Thank you' part, is it redundant?

Comment: Read more [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/etiquette-on-addressing-fellow-users) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/17994), but basically the point is to differentiate this site from forums where niceties, sign-offs and other chatter reduce usability. Several aspects of the site's layout and programming (including the character limit I'm now approaching) are in place with the explicit aim of focusing the site down to Q&A only and thereby maximizing its helpfulness to future visitors.

Comment: I would say either “...logo **at** top right **on** the page...” (no “the” before “top right”) or “...logo **in the** top right **corner of** the page.” “...the top right...” sounds awkward without a noun like “corner” (“sector”, “quadrant”, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we use *at* for a **point**, *in* for an **enclosed area/space** and *on* for a **surface or plane**.

In this case you are talking about one particular point, I think "logo at the top right of the page" is preferred.

*On the page* fits in an instance where you have panel or sidebar. For example, putting a small sidebar *on* the page. There, the area is larger/bigger and not at specific point so 'panel at the left side of the page' may not go well.